# error: ‘cv::fisheye’ has not been declared

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I wanted to write a camera calibration for a 140 deg fisheye lens.
As the normal calibration of opencv is not working with these lenses I found that there seems to be a cv::fisheye module within the calib3d bundle.

But every time I try to compile my code the g++ states:

```
error: ‘cv::fisheye’ has not been declared
```

the problem is that the documentation of opencv 2.4.11 contains the methods and the additional namespace.

I have the following includes in my c++ file:

```
//OPENCV Stuff
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
```

the call of the function looks like that:

```
double rmsL = cv::fisheye::calibrate(objectPoints, imagePointsLeft, imagesize, cameraMatrices[LEFT], distCoeffs[LEFT], rvecs, tvecs);
```

I am compiling with the include path for pkg-config

```
OPENCV = `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

In fact the normal calibration stuff is working properly as well as any other opencv related stuff.

Is anyone out there able to help me with tis problem?
It would be quiet nice to use the fisheye calibration because of the wide fov and its improvements for calculating the disparity map.

Cheers hGen

Comment: Does it work correctly?   https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/74e58ddbb1f2f80631ea794c8ccf158c3a60cde8   *Disable the broken fisheye undistortImage test* https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/6df1198e8b1ea4925cbce943a1dc6549f27d8be2/modules/calib3d/test/test_fisheye.cpp

Comment: Being new to opencv - what is the mechanism by which cv::fisheye namespace is supposed to "appear" ? fisheye.hpp and fisheye.cpp does have this calibrate method but they are internal. Are they supposed to be provided by calib3d? That is how I read this: 

http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html

Comment: Yep I think that it is part of the calib3d library. The problem is that it is just available if you build the library by Hand. Otherwise via 'apt-get', 'brew'  or other package managers the fisheye namespace is not available at all.

Comment: I managed to get it to run but just with OpenCV 3.0 but also there the functions within the namespace are not working properly. There are segfaults etc when using any of the funcfinn

Answer (score 1):

Do you use these compile options?

```
-I/pathto/opencv/include -L/pathto/library lopencv_core
```

Answer (score 1):

`error: ‘cv::fisheye’ has not been declared` is a compilation error. Not a linker error. Which means, your compiler is not able to look for defnitions of `cv::fisheye`.

Either try to give explicit path.

`#include "path/to/opencv2/.....h"`

or

Provide the include path in `-I` switch.

`g++ -I<path to opencv2> *.cpp -l <path to opencv2 lib> -o <target-name>`

Comment: I.e. for OpenCV 2.4.x I need to add `#include "modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.hpp"`.

Comment: I would recommend using absolute path.